# i want to return false when instantiating an object

Tags: javascript

well, this is not an easy question, but in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DpdVd/) you will see a simplified version of  what it is i am trying to do:

I want to instantiate an object, do all the operation i need to initialize it, but i want the statement:

```
var obj = new class;
```

to return 'false' to obj given some conditions.

here's the code anyhow:

```
var cl = function(id){
   this.init(id);
   if(this.id > 5){
       return false;
   }
};


cl.prototype = {
    init: function(id){
        this.id = id;                        

    }
}

var arr = [];

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var obj = new cl(i);
    if(obj){
         arr.push(obj);
    }
}

console.log(arr);
```

I know the end result can be achieved by creating a control property to the object, but i am curious to if there is any pattern to do this cleaner.

Comment: you can't return anything but the object created when `new` is used. so I would do `throw new Error("Invalid id")` and abort the operation.

Comment: you can also return an other object (null is a value, although typeof null is object), everything else returned is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe not exactly what you've asked, but a solution could be to use the factory pattern. Ofcourse you'd have to call the `factory` method instead of the constructor. checkout [this fidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/DpdVd/1/)

Comment: btw; this is not the use the factory pattern is intended for... but it does work, and does create either an object or a boolean for you. And if it works, what the hell ;)

Comment: thanks, it is also not what i was looking for, but cudos for presenting me with a valid alternative